# "Go Green" or "Goes Green"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

So, I want to make an environment movement and I see "Go Green" is hyped and suitable for the movement. But what I want to know is, is it should be "(my company's name) Go Green" or "(my company's name) Goes Green"?
Besides, I wonder, does "Go Green" is a single term for something or is it a just a sentence? I've seen some example of companies using Go Green, but my colleagues say it should be Goes Green.

Comment: Should be "[Company Name] goes green!" or "We are going green!"

Comment: But what I want to know is, *should it be*...

Comment: *Company go green* is an instruction to Company. *Company goes green* is a (short) report *about* Company.

Answer (score 2):

Often, you'll see "Go Green!" on banners and placards because people are campaigning, and trying to get other people to become more environmentally friendly.

"Go Green!" is an imperative, with implied second-person subject ("*You should* Go Green!")

So, in your case (because the subject is not the reader of the notice, but rather the company) the correct phrase would be:

> [Company Name] goes green!